# Python script that set baud rate in raw

Tags: python

I need help for python script that set baud rate in raw. Because on my raspberry after use `sudo stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 2400 raw` and then reboot I lose baud rate and should execuse manually that command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you posted your existing Python code.

You could use the following:

```
import serial

port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
baud = 2400

serialPort = serial.Serial(port, baudrate = baud, timeout = 0.5)
```